# Is Namor the Only Hybrid?

Tags: comics, marvel

Are there others with one  Homo mermanus parent and one Homo sapiens parent?  Or is Namor the only hybrid between the two?

I know it's simple, but I've just started reading some old Sub-Mariner comics and what I've seen there and online doesn't seem to indicate any other hybrids and the level of distrust among the Atlanteans for humans seems so high, I'd think the number of children with one parent from each world would be almost non-existant.

Comment: Sometimes you just gotta wonder why you get a downvote.  I don't all the story lines, didn't know a name to search for, and what I found on Atlanteans and other terms didn't give me an answer -- so am I not supposed to ask on something I want to know?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's also his cousin [Namora](http://marvel.com/universe/Namora).

Answer (score 1):

Lyra of Lemuria was a hybrid whose mother was an airbreather and father was a Lemurian.